# Default empty constructor in templated struct

Tags: c++, templates, closures

I'm reading Paul Fultz blog entry about [Pipeable functions](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2021-10/cplusplus-pipeable/) in which there is what he defines as a pipe_closure

```
1 template<class F>
2 struct pipe_closure : F
3 {
4     template<class... Xs>
5     pipe_closure(Xs&&... xs) : F(std::forward<Xs>(xs)...)
6     { }
7 };
```

I'm aware of the [Perfect forwarding](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm) problem, what is is on how it get solved by `std::forward` after (templated expressions) type inference.

What I'm not catching is what line 5 is actually intending to do as a whole. My current understanding of this block of code is that we are inheriting from a templated type which in the future will be considered a functor (by inheriting from an object overriding `()`), but why to use a member initializer of an struct that is empty in itself.

e.g. of an struct from which we can inherit (used in the same post)

```
1 struct add_one_f
2 {
3     template<class T>
4     auto operator()(T x) const
5     {
6        return x + 1;
7     }
8 };
9 const pipe_closure<add_one_f> add_one = {};
```

If we remove line 5 of the first block the code compiles and runs successfully (under gcc-12 at Fedora linux), so, could someone please give me a hint of what the author is trying to do? I need help for this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add a non empty constructor to `add_one_f` and then change `add_one = {};` by `add_one = {/*your constructor parameter*/};`.

Comment: I mean that's true, that'll fail inevitably but I was searching for a justification in this particular scenario (which just seems to be for extending the code).

Comment: Inherit constructor might be better BTW (`using F::F;`) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/75dEhb1he).

Comment: Why would that be a better option?

Comment: Functors don't have to be stateless.

Comment: template constructor has caveat, as it might be a better match than copy constructor `auto add2 = add_one;` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cPT37oz9n).